# Firewall/Router upgrade

Tags: firewall, router

We've been using a SonicWall TZ170 for several years, it's been working fine with occasional glitches.

Now we switched to a 100Mpbs broadband, and the firewall has become the bottleneck for internet access because its max throughput is around 20-30Mpbs.

Any ideas for a replacement? Brand/Model?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the Cisco ASA 5510. It has a maximum throughput of 300Mbps which is enough for you. It can also Active/Passive clustering in case you want to go down the high availability road.

In case you need to evolve, it can do content filtering (CSC-SSM), Intrusion Prevention (SSM-AIP) and IPsec/SSL VPN.

Comment: Same here, been using a Cisco PIX (now ASA) 515E for ages without any large problems. ASDM is both powerful and quite simple once you get the hang of it.

Comment: +1 for Cisco 5510.  I've got a couple of these in my network, they're fantastic devices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Juniper fan so I'd suggest an SRX100, or SRX210 if you want more features.

Other options would be a Cisco 890 or 1941 routers.

There's also products like the [Astaro gateways](http://www.astaro.com/products/hardware-appliances) for really crazy features.

Answer (score 2):

You could even go with a dedicated PC with a package like m0n0wall or PfSense. From my experience, an old P4 2.6 gHz with 256 MB RAM comfortably routes at 100/100 with PfSense.

The interface is quite intuitive and of course, there is the option to SSH in and get a commandline.

Also, from what I read, load-balancing or failover is quite easy to set up, so reliability (because of old or non-server-grade hardware) might not be as much of an issue as it would seem. You can also backup the configuration quite easily so if you have some identical boxes, replacement shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: +1 for pfsense, it's great.